# Componentizing parts of a Spring Boot app to provide new functionality by dropping in jars?

Tags: spring-boot, osgi

I have a Spring Boot application I want to resale to clients. I want it to serve as an entry-point/framework for multiple functions that can be individually sold/added over time.

Ideally, the base spring boot app/jar can be provided to users. On startup, the app would scan the current working directory for any jar files. If it finds a jar file, it would automatically make the functionality available in the base app to the users.

There may be better ways to do this, but already have the base spring boot app developed and this seems like one logical way to do it. Would OSGI be the right answer for this scenario?

Or are their other ways to provide componentized/bundled functionality to a Spring Boot app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory OSGi would be better suited for this kind of thing, because it allows you to install new components during runtime, not requiring a restart. OSGi also provides by design better mechanisms for encapsulating functionality in independent components.

But that said I am not sure if that is the right approach in general. What happens, if the customer does not pay for your component anymore? What happens if the customer paid for the component and you want to sell an update and they don’t want to pay and now you have to support more than more version etc.

There are many ways to think of scenarios that would complicate the whole thing.

As far as I can tell, most products ship everything and then you pay a license fee. Depending on the licenses you bought different features are then „unlocked.

Most of the time those licenses are just some sort of “cryptographic” key that only the issuer can check. Think of public/private key mechanisms. I bet there are more options.

There was just recently an interesting blog post by the Gitlab engineering team on this sort of topic: [GitLab might move to a single Rails codebase](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/02/21/merging-ce-and-ee-codebases/)

If you really want to go with this you might also want to have a look at the new [Java module system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System), that was introduced in Java 9. Although it appears that this is not yet [100% supported by Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13799).

*Personally*, having worked with OSGi for the last 9 years, I probably would recommend to do this with Spring Boot. This is based on the *subjective feeling* that Spring Boot is a little bit more modern and has a bigger community. There is no OSGi framework (like Spring Boot) that would get me excited at the moment to do a project with, although the overall idea of OSGi is still great. But as I said, this is *my* opinion, which is not necessarily “right”.

Comment: Hi Jens, was just looking and I never accepted or thanked you for the answer. Thanks so much for your help on this, helped changed the direction of our project in a really beneficial way, and ended up going the Spring Boot and Licensing route. Thanks so much for your detailed and helpful answer on this!